# Saving a UIImage as a PNG, can't load image after restarting app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am using this to save a UIImage as a PNG

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *generatedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"background%f.png", timeInMiliseconds];
    NSString  *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:generatedString];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(customBackground) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

I am saving pngPath into a plist from above then using the string in this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:string];
```

as string, the string shows up right and I can see the image file at the exact location it shows.

Now the strange part is as long as I don't close the app the method works fine, but if I close and reopen the app the UIImage file just stays nil. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would try loading the file data with `
dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` providing a error return and if the data is nil print the error. Then if that is successful use `imageWithData'. That way you can split the problem.

Comment: You need to do further diagnostics to narrow down the precise point of failure: You should confirm whether the problem rests in the retrieval of the path from persistent storage (the plist) or whether the problem is the retrieval of the image having successfully determined the path. So, log the `string` you use with `imageWithContentsOfFile` and make sure it's ok, i.e. the fully qualified path, not just the filename, not `nil`, etc. Also actually examine the PNG file and make sure it looks like what you expected it to. We can't help you until you identify precisely where the problem rests.

Comment: Yeah the string is right and the png looks good when I browse to it. I'll try using with error and report back in a few.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot...

The string saved and retrieved was missing a "/" between the Documents and file name. Added it in and it works. Now I'm curious how it ever worked when app never closed. Thanks for the help guys. :)

Comment: The code in your question used `stringByAppendingPathComponent`, which should prevent that. Did you happen to use `stringByAppendingString` or something like that instead?

Comment: I copy and pasted just as it was. I'm not sure how it happened. Since it saved to the right spot and I just passed the string it used to save. But when the string was placed in my plist somehow that last "/" was missing. I should probably do a bit more testing and see exactly what is happening it could be a bug I may need to report.